# How can I convert .doc to .txt without getting a bunch of garbage in my txt file?

Tags: windows, command-line, microsoft-word, batch

SO.. I'm trying to rename a bunch of word documents (~80) to .txt files with a batch so I can then search all of them for the string I need (I've already figured out this batch file). I just need help converting my .doc files to .txt without getting a bunch of garbage in the .txt files. What happens right now when I use:

REN *.doc *.txt

The converted .txt files have a bunch of garbage in them. When I individually 'save as' a word document as a 'plain text' file it opens an 'encode as' screen and then saves as default windows. There is no garbage in this file, but I don't feel like individually using 'save as' to encode ~80 documents in this folder. I've tried to use:

chcp 1252
REN *.doc *.txt

I had no luck with this either. Any help would be great!

Comment: Renaming a file does not change its content, or convert it from one format to another.  `Save as...` will change the format as you wish.

Comment: I guess I don't understand your suggestion. The 'REN *.doc *.txt' is in a notepad saved as .bat so I can run it in the folder with all the word document files to change them to .txt? I'm new to using .bat files so pardon me if I think you're misunderstanding me.

Comment: you can use Macro, to save files as text or use a tool like MultiDoc Converter to do the job.

Comment: The extensions have nothing to do with the file content. The extensions are part of the file name and are just there to help Windows know what program to open the file with. When you use `REN *.doc *.txt`, all it does is renames the .doc files to .txt, but it doesn't change their format so they're still Word documents. All you've done is make Windows think you've converted the file from a Word document to a text file, but you haven't actually done it.

Answer (score 1):

#### How can I convert `.doc` to `.txt`?

You can use something like docx2txt:

> Docx2txt is a Perl based command-line utility to convert (even corrupted) Microsoft docx documents to reasonably formatted text files, along with appropriate character conversions. Apart from Perl it also requires a command line unzipping program like unzip/7z/pkzipc/wzunzip.
>
> Features
>
> - Consists of (core) Perl and (wrapper) Unix/Windows shell scripts and a configuration file, with provision for maintaining separate
>     system-wide configuration file and individual user-level configuration
>     files.
> - Perl script also works with input/output redirection, and is useful in viewing docx file content directly with editors like vim,
>     emacs, and file browsers like mc (midnight commander).
> - Can recover text from damaged docx documents in many cases.
> - Short line justifications, showing hyperlink and many character conversions (missing in MS text conversion).
> - Handles (bullet, decimal, letter, roman) lists along with indentation.
> - Installation via Makefiles and Windows batch file. On non-Windows systems scripts and configuration file can be installed in separate
>     directories.
> - Can conveniently be used to build a web based docx document conversion service.

Source [docx2txt](https://sourceforge.net/projects/docx2txt/)

Comment: Err.. not sure this is useful for me, I don't have this program. If chcp 'code' would work I'd be on my way, but it doesn't seem to. :(

Comment: @Scott You need to install it. Using `chcp` does not magically convert the contents of a word doc in to a test file.

Comment: Word files are not plain text files.

Comment: I know this ... from what I read it seemed like chcp is what I needed to change the FORMAT of the text file.. not 'magically convert the .doc to .txt'.

Comment: @Scott have you even read this answer?

Comment: @Scott Please read [chcp](http://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html) - "the choice of code page will determine the set of characters displayed." It doesn't convert anything. It will not change a word document into a plain text file.